# Is my password/authentication strategy for a REST API good?

Tags: c#, sql, security, rest, asp.net-web-api

Okay, good is subjective, but it fits better in the title.  What I really want to know is if there are any glaring deficiencies in this password management/authentication strategy.  I am also curious about performance.  I am trying to use PBKDF2 to authenticate but I am not really sure if that is a good idea for a RESTful web service.  I can find some parts of this question answered here and there but I have never found one comprehensive top to bottom answer.  Here goes, this is my entire strategy.

Background:

- Service is an ASP.NET Web Api project in C#
- Backend is MS SQL server
- Credentials are sent over HTTPS using Basic authentication, i.e. 'authorization: Basic username:password'
- API will be consumed by Andriod app, ios app and web site

First, the backend:

```
create table [dbo].[User] (
    [Name] varchar(50) collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI not NULL primary key clustered,
    [Password] varchar(28) collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS not NULL,
    [Salt] varchar(28) not NULL)
```

the stored procedure to create the user:

```
create procedure [dbo].[User_Create] 
    @Name varchar(50),
    @Salt varchar(50),
    @Password varchar(50)
as 
    insert into [dbo].[User]([Name], [Salt], [Password])
    values(@Name, @Salt, @Password)
```

and the stored procedure to get the user:

```
create procedure [dbo].[User_Get] 
    @Name varchar(50)
as 
    select *
    from [dbo].[User]
    where [Name] = @Name
```

With the backend I am curious if the data types selected for the name, password and salt are appropriate.

This is the code that creates a new user and persists it to the backend.  This is probably what I am most concerned about, both from a security stand point as well as performance.

```
public void CreateUser(string username, string password)
{
    int hashLength = 20;
    int saltLength = 20;
    int hashIterations = 1000;
    using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(this._ConnectionString))
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[User_Create]"))
    {
        Rfc2898DeriveBytes pbkdf2 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, saltLength, hashIterations);
        string salt = Convert.ToBase64String(pbkdf2.Salt);
        string hashPassword = Convert.ToBase64String(pbkdf2.GetBytes(hashLength));

        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", username);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Salt", salt);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", hashPassword);
        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

And here is the code to authenticate the user.  This essentially just executes the stored procedure, calls `ValidatePassword` to perform the PBKDF2 and returns a `User` object back to the Web API message handler which sets the Principal (roles have not been implemented yet):

```
public User AuthenticateUser(string username, string password)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(this._ConnectionString))
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[User_Get]"))
    {
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", username);
        command.Connection = connection;

        connection.Open();
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (reader.Read() && this.ValidatePassword(password, reader["Salt"].ToString(), reader["Password"].ToString()))
            {
                return new User()
                    {
                        Name = username,
                        CustomerId = reader["CustomerId"].ToString()
                    };
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is `ValidatePassword`, which the above code relies on to validate the password (in case that wasn't obvious).  I also want to make sure I got this one right.

```
private bool ValidatePassword(string password, string salt, string hashedPassword)
{
    int hashLength = 20;
    int hashIterations = 1000;
    byte[] saltBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(salt);
    Rfc2898DeriveBytes pbkdf2 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, saltBytes, hashIterations);

    byte[] hashBytes = pbkdf2.GetBytes(hashLength);
    string hash = Convert.ToBase64String(hashBytes);

    // Security Decisions For String Comparisons
    //
    // If you are making a security decision (such as whether to allow access to a system resource) based on the 
    // result of a string comparison or a case change, you should not use the invariant culture. Instead, you 
    // should perform a case-sensitive or case-insensitive ordinal comparison by calling a method that includes 
    // a StringComparison parameter and supplying either StringComparison.Ordinal or 
    // StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase as an argument. Code that performs culture-sensitive string operations 
    // can cause security vulnerabilities if the current culture is changed or if the culture on the computer 
    // that is running the code differs from the culture that is used to test the code. In contrast, an ordinal 
    // comparison depends solely on the binary value of the compared characters.
    //
    // Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx

    return hash.Equals(hashedPassword, StringComparison.Ordinal);
}
```

Comment: You may also want to use a constant-time string comparison to prevent timing attacks.

Comment: I assume you know asp.net has its own membership structure? (though I think you don't really care, you have your own system)

Comment: Don't assume anything, I am very new to security.  That being said, membership providers did turn up in my research.  Some people seemed to love them but it looked like quite a few others were not very impressed with them.  In the end I thought it would be better if I took the time to understand the subject myself rather than use technology that abstracted it away.

Comment: @Blender: The constant-time string comparison is interesting.  Can that much information really be gleaned from the string comparison?  I would think the variable nature of the latency in the API calls plus the time stretching of the PBKDF2 function would make it difficult to accurately measure the time of the string comparison.  In any event, how would this be accomplished in C#?  Convert each string to a byte array and then 'xor' the bytes in each string and sum them up to make sure they are 0?

Comment: The `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` implements the `IDisposable` interface (via the `DeriveBytes` ancestor) and therefore should be wrapped in a `using` statement in order to be properly deterministically disposed.

Answer (score 0):

highly opinionated answer.

why do this yourself when there are many off the shelf (as in completely free and well tested) implementations?

By all means do this as an exercise (it a fascinating area imo) but timing attacks are just the tip of the iceberg.

the first rule of security is if you are doing anything involving encryption yourself you are probably venturing into an area that you should ensure you do very little in. Eg use an owin or open auth provider or active directory. But step away from the weapon.

dont become the next muppet to leak a ton of data by doing it yourself.

have a look at federated security, saml tokens and sts providers